# Can I use multiple domains for a single app / single client ID?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, localhost, google-authentication

I am using google auth for my web app hosted on multiple domains.  Can I use the same client ID I obtain from [google](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) for each domain.

They are listed as **authorized redirect URIs** in the consle.

For example, I have one for localhost, mydomain, my-test-domain, etc.

```
https://localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
https://mydomain/auth/google/callback
https://my-test-domain/auth/google/callback
```

Comment: hmm good question, was it giving an error? might have some tips https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain

Comment: I can't tell what is going on, mydomain works, and my-test-domain seems to work, but I'm not sure.  I'm trying different test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can specify multiple URIs. The URIs can contain different domain names.

Comment: Thanks is there any good online reference material for this?  I read much of it but never got to the part about multiple URIs.  I can not get a new domain of mine to authenticate and am trying to narrow down the cause.

Comment: @favor - this is an area I work in. I do not have a specific reference link for you.

Answer (score 0):

- On an OAuth key credential for a `Web Application` you can set `Authorised redirect URIs` and `Authorised JavaScript origins`.
- The redirect URIs are the authorised addresses that the OAuth service can send responses to.
- If your application also makes requests to OAuth service from the client-side Javascript to access Google APIs, you also must configure the `Authorised redirect URIs` for that credential key.
- Both configurations accept different domains.

###### References:

- https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849#zippy=%2Cweb-applications
- https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python